# Swift: Static Variable Suddenly becomes Nil

Tags: swift, static

I have this class where I have two static variables which are closures. When project launch I assign the function (which basically does the presentation of another controller). The strange thing is this code was working and suddenly it stopped working.

```
public class AppCapabilityInjector {

    public static var routeToWebView: ((_ presentationController: UIViewController, _ url: URL) -> ())?

    public static var routeToMenu: ((_ presentationController: UIViewController) -> ())?
}
```

I tried to print after assigning the values to these static variables, I am seeing function as values. But when I try to use this value in another framework `AppCapabilityInjector.routeToMenu` it becomes nil.

I also tried `didSet` on `routeToMenu`, only once it is called and printing function as value.

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting any value to your static properties? Show you code context.

Comment: Actually I debug the problem and caught even a strange thing. We have this class in a framework which was earlier dynamic so everything was working. When we made that framework static and as that static library was part of 3 other sub frameworks in our app.. it was creating three copies of this class. Hence behaviour was undefined. Can you help me to understand why converting framework from dynamic to static lib is creating this problem?

Comment: try making your class a singleton, `public class AppCapabilityInjector {`  `public static let shared = AppCapabilityInjector()` `public var routeToWebView: ((_ presentationController: UIViewController, _ url: URL) -> ())?` `public var routeToMenu: ((_ presentationController: UIViewController) -> ())?` `private init() { }` `}`

Comment: And access your properties as `AppCapabilityInjector.share.routeToWebView` this will make sure you have only one instance of your shared `AppCapabilityInjector` class

Comment: I did this.. and in private init, I put a log.. it is creating a different instance for each framework. Looks Like the behaviour of static library is different if we add in multiple targets in same project.

Comment: @AnkurPrakash Did you find out the issue? How are you using this library as a dependency ?